# ClickHouse быстрая выборка уникальных значений

Tags: clickhouse

В ClickHouse имеется таблица на 6 миллиардов записей логов событий.
Есть поле с именами пользователей, поле с предметом и поле с действием над предметом.
Есть ли способ быстро получить результат с именем пользователя и списком его уникальных предметов?

Запросы видов

```
SELECT distinct(item) FROM table WHERE user_id = 'Вася'
```

и

```
SELECT item FROM table WHERE user_id = 'Вася' GROUP BY item
```

работают 31 и 22 секунды соответственно.

Число итераций измеряется сотнями тысяч.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если устраивает не гарантированно точное решение, то можно ещё попробовать

```
SELECT item FROM table WHERE user_id = 'Вася' LIMIT 1 BY cityHash64(item)
```

Хотя я сомневаюсь, что оно будет работать существенно быстрее.

> Число итераций измеряется сотнями тысяч.

Какие итерации вы имеете ввиду? Если речь идёт о том, чтобы выполнить много однотипных запросов, то это лучше избегать. Один большой запрос лучше многих маленьких.

Чтобы получить всё за один запрос, можете ещё попробовать

```
SELECT user_id, groupUniqArray(item) FROM table GROUP BY user_id
```

Если пользователей много и оперативки недостаточно, то можно разбить на несколько запросов по диапазонам user_id, либо включить агрегацию во внешней памяти.